# Make a relationship based on points and fences

Tags: postgis, geodjango, geofencing

I have two models on geodjango, one for tracks and one for fencing, I am trying to match both of them but I couldnt get it working as I spected. My target is check each point if it is inside a fence.

My models are

```
class Track(models.Model):
    avl = models.ForeignKey('avls.AVLUnit', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=9)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=9)
    altitude = models.IntegerField()
    speed = models.IntegerField()
    course = models.IntegerField()
    satellites = models.IntegerField()
    extra = models.TextField()
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=512, default="-")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Tracks'

    def __str__(self):

        return "%s-%s-%s-%s" % (
            str(self.avl),
            str(self.timestamp),
            str(self.latitude),
            str(self.longitude)
        )

class Geofence(models.Model):
    TYPE_GEOZONES = (
        (1, 'LINE'),
        (2, 'POLYGON'),
        (3, 'CIRCLE'),
    )
    avl_resource = models.ForeignKey(
        'AVLResource',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    geofence_id = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    geofence_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, unique=False)
    geofence_description = models.TextField()
    geofence_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPE_GEOZONES, default=1)
    geofence_data = models.GeometryField()
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I have a query for make it possible, however I am not realy sure if this is ok, and I would prefer it on a django way

```
SELECT a.latitude, a.longitude, b.geofence_name FROM tracks_track a, avl_resources_geofence b WHERE ST_Within(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(a.longitude, a.latitude), 4326), b.geofence_data) = True and a.timestamp::date = date '2018-02-23' order by a.timestamp DESC limit 10;

   latitude    |   longitude   |           geofence_name           
---------------+---------------+-----------------------------------
 -14.882885000 | -71.312260000 | GF00
 -14.864581667 | -71.325765000 | GF01
 -14.963245000 | -71.375826667 | GF02
 -14.864731667 | -71.325960000 | GF03
 -14.886156667 | -71.313855000 | GF04
 -14.864593333 | -71.325746667 | GF05
 -14.926816667 | -71.347586667 | GF06
 -14.882885000 | -71.312260000 | GF07
 -14.933970000 | -71.346448333 | GF08
 -14.944961667 | -71.378663333 | GF09
```

Finally, my question is how to build a query using geodjango or postgis to buld a relationship between this both models / tables or having and optmized way on solve this issue without loosing performance

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in the model implicitly, that is to say, without evaluating it when an object is created and updated, for example.

What you might do is when you are doing something with a point, you could have a function that checks whether it is in one of your geofences. You don't need to do this with the built in Geodjango filters, so you don't need to write your own SQL. See [the docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/geoquerysets/#std:fieldlookup-gis-contains).

For example, something like this:

```
Geofence.objects.filter(poly__contains=point_geom)
```

where the `point_geom` is a GEOS point object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is close that I am looking for, but I also have done an edit on my question in order on clarify my spect results